# How to mount a shared folder on Windows 7 host as home directory for Linux guest under VMware Player

Tags: windows, linux, vmware, shared-folders, home-directory

The host computer is running Windows 7 Ulitmate, the guest OS will be Linux (the brand to de decided later; likely Debian 4 or CentOS 6). The hypervisor is VMware Player 4. My problem is: how do I get the Linux installer to mount a shared folder (on a host NTFS partition) during the installation phase so that I may use said folder as my home directory in Linux? As far as I know, using shared folders in VMware configuration is only possible when VMtools are already installed in a running guest. In other words, it is required to use a folder on the host filesystem as my /home directory branch with a Linux guest (it needs to be accessible by Windows since that is where data sharing will occur), not to create a separate Linux partition for home on the virtual disk. I would like to have this settled right at the installation phase. I've thought about exporting NFS shares via Windows, but it turns out that Windows 7 doesn't have NFS hosting capabilities. I've tired to find out whether SUA has tools for this but it appears it doesn't - only previous versions did, according to my research. Because this is all new to me, I might've overlooked something obvious, misunderstood something about shares and NFS, or whatever.
I also have an empty 20G vhd that might be useful...

Answer (score 1):

During Linux installation, if $(FOO_DISTRO) is worth its salt, it'll let you customize the partition layout. Just don't create a /home partition. It'll make /home a directory on your / drive and create your first user there. Once you're booted up, edit `/etc/fstab` and mount your `hfgs` volume as `/home`. Switch to `init 1` (single-user mode), and move your directories under `/home` on the `/` partition to `/` on the shared volume. You can do this by temporarily mounting the `hgfs` share on e.g. `/media/shared` and do `sudo mv /home/* /media/shared`.

If $(FOO_DISTRO) rocks your socks then it'll let you manually edit the `/etc/fstab` to be installed to the host instead of forcing you through a graphical partition editor. If $(FOO_DISTRO) rocks your socks **squared**, it'll come preinstalled with (or let you install at install-time) `open-vm-tools` so that you can mount vmware `hgfs` volumes out of the box. If you can do that, then you don't even have to perform the switcheroo I described; just edit `/etc/fstab` (as it is to be installed on the guest, **not** the `/etc/fstab` of the live/installation environment) with the appropriate mount line.

See your local VMware Workstation manual for details.